# Removing last segment in paper.js (undo)

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I've been trying to create an undo function that would remove the last segment from my path in paper.js. I'm having trouble because the function expects an index, but I can't seem to get one. I've tried:

```
    undo: function(){
        path.removeSegment(path.segments.lastsegment);
        path.removeSegment(path.segments.lastsegment.index);
        path.segments.lastsegment.remove;
    },
```

and more... None seem to work. Has anyone done this with paper function instead of making your own index? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do it. If anyone has a cleaner way, feel free to share.

```
path.removeSegments(((path.segments).length)-1);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).